# CMake building multiple libraries in the same project

Tags: cmake, cross-platform, shared-objects

I have a specific CMake project I would like to build as both a static lib and a shared object (Linux only). The relevant part of the CMake file:

```
...

# Static lib
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})

# Build shared object in Linux only
if(UNIX)
    set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
    add_library("${PROJECT_NAME}_SHARED" SHARED ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})
endif(UNIX)

link_directories(${ILI_EXTERNAL_LIB_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${ILI_EXTERNAL_LIBS} IliLib PlantModel)
```

I can figure out why the shared object is not being built, when I add a message within the Unix block, it gets printed during the make build. The rest of this cmake file only sets variables and declares the project name.

Any tips for how to go about debugging this issue? On both Windows and Linux, it only builds the static lib at present.

---

Edit:
[Link to CMake and Make log outputs](https://pastebin.com/CcJ0PLJ7).

Comment: This snippet looks fine to me.  Do you see it listed if you do `make help`?

Comment: Yes, I don't see any issue with the CMake code you've provided. It may be helpful to provide the full `make` output?

Comment: @StephenNewell Thanks for the suggestions. I don't have the Linux toolchain locally so I'll have to interrogate the Jenkins builds to find out.

Comment: @squareskittles I have attached the log outputs, they may be difficult to follow as this make file is being called from a larger project.

Comment: Thanks, for the example CMake code you provided, what is `${PROJECT_NAME}`? Also, if possible, please add the Make log to your question post *as text* instead of a link to external site, as many folks cannot access such sites.

Comment: @squareskittles I believe ${PROJECT_NAME} is just the string which was passed to the PROJECT() command at the top the cmake file ("SimulatorLib").  I would have pasted the log into the question except it was too long and I did not truncate it.

Comment: Hmmm, your `make` log doesn't show the `SimulatorLib` CMake target (or `SimulatorLib_SHARED`) being built at all. At least, not from what I saw. Are you sure the code in your CMake snippet is reached?

Comment: @squareskittles If I add a message to that point, it gets printed in the CMake log. The static lib definitely gets built and the Unix switch works as expected, running  out of ideas.

Comment: `RUN make IliadLib_test` - You (or your script) calls `make` with a **specific target**. So `make` builds only this target and its dependencies.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Awesome, that was it, I failed to spot it because it was an artefact of the previous structure of the project. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was suggested by @Tsyvarev, trivial error on my part.

The static lib was being built because it was a dependency of another build target. I had not explicitly run "Make" on the SimulatorLib project.

CMake messages appear in the CMake log irrespective of whether that particular project is being built.